# Why is nano ignoring the first line in files?

Tags: linux, nano

I've sshed into Server A and Server B from Windows Vista.
I've sshed into Server A and Server B from Windows XP.

In all 4 cases, when I edit a file with nano, the first line does not show up in nano and if I save the file, the first line is not saved (often losing important data!)

Comment: Use `od -c` on the first 100 or so bytes to find out.

Comment: What program are you using to ssh from Windows?

Comment: Is there something special about the files you're editing, or is this reproducible with all files?

Comment: What version of nano is this?  (`nano -V`)

Comment: @blahdiblah it's happened with at least 2 files

Comment: @uSlackr Cygwin

Comment: GNU nano version 1.3.12 (compiled 14:20:47, Jan  9 2007)
 Email: nano@nano-editor.org    Web: http://www.nano-editor.org/
 Compiled options: --enable-color --enable-extra --enable-multibuffer --enable-nanorc --enable-utf8

Comment: Not an explanation, but if possible you could upgrade to a more recent version of nano (latest is 2.2.6 as of now), and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Is there anything in your nanorc files?  (`SYSCONFDIR/nanorc` and `~/.nanorc`, I assume that `SYSCONFDIR` is `/etc`, but ymmv.)

Comment: Can you login to server A and B directly? If so, do you have the same problem there? Do you see the Nano header line at the top of the window? Have you tried to make the ssh window larger on your windows box(assuming a 24 line terminal but only showing 22)?

Comment: @chuck No, I don't have direct access. I don't think it's the size of the window, I'm on a 24" monitor.

Comment: The issue with how many lines are displayed doesn't have much to do the size of your screen. The issue I'm wondering about would depend on the program you are using to connect to servers A and B. A standard terminal is usually 24 lines tall by 80 characters wide. I'm wondering if the program is only showing 22 lines and causing problems for nano.

Comment: @chuck - here's what I see in nano: http://i.imgur.com/lrys2.png

Comment: @chuck - here's what I see in vi: http://i.imgur.com/PitmE.png

Comment: In this case, it's not cutting off the whole line but part of it. In nano, if I hold the right arrow (to run the cursor to the end of the line), the line ends up looking like this: http://i.imgur.com/mPISX.png

Comment: That is weird. I see you are using Cygwin and can't say I have always had the best luck with Cygwin. I know this isn't the answer to your question but you might want to try putty and run nano or vi on server A and B. Your Cygwin images lead me to believe that your terminal isn't redrawing the characters the way it should be. A Ctrl-L might fix it temporarily and making sure your Cygwin is up to date might not hurt.